# ASP.NET Core Web API that calls web APIs via client credential flow - MSAL.NET or Microsoft.Identity.Web?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-identity-web

Going to have a web api that calls another web api requiring the OAuth client credential flow. The web api does not need authentication.

Should I use MSAL.NET instead of Microsoft.Identity.Web in this case?

I have read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-migration-confidential-client?tabs=authcode and https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/web-apis, but they do not provide a clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing this document [MSAL.NET or Microsoft.Identity.Web](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/MSAL.NET-or-Microsoft.Identity.Web). You should use Microsoft.Identity.Web. Protecting api with azure is not complicated.

1. Login to Azure, choose azure active directory. remember your primary domain.
   [image]
   [image]
2. Choose app registrations - new registration - input whatever name and continue.  Remember its client ID.
   [image]
3. Choose expose an api, then click set . Then save and remember this application ID URI.
   [image]
4. Choose Ceritificates and Secrets, add new client secret, copy and remember the secret value right away.
   [image]
5. You can try with this console client to get a token and access webapi. modify the client ID ,client secret to yours, make the scope equals to your application ID URI + "/.default" .Don't forget install IdentityModel package.

```
using IdentityModel.Client;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

internal class Program
{
    private static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        // request for token
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var tokenResponse = await client.RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync(new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest
        {
            Address = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/6c1ec436-4626-4a07-836f-0510d13f5c6b/oauth2/v2.0/token",
            ClientId = "your client ID",
            ClientSecret = "your client secrect",
            Scope = "{your application ID URI}/.default"
        });

        if (tokenResponse.IsError)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(tokenResponse.Error);
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(tokenResponse.Json);


        // using token to access API
        var apiClient = new HttpClient();
        apiClient.SetBearerToken(tokenResponse.AccessToken);

        var response = await apiClient.GetAsync("https://localhost:7171/weatherforecast");
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
        }
        else
        {
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(JArray.Parse(content));
        }

    }
}
```

6. Run this client, remember the token you get, decode it in JWT.IO ,remember the iss value.
   [image]
   [image]
7. Create a webapi, use "[Authorize]" attribute on your api. In the program.cs file . add authentication & authorize services. Make the authority equals to the iss value you just decoded.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
        .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
        {
            options.Authority = "{the decoded iss value}";

            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
         });
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
```

Don't forget `app.UseAuthorization();`
Run your api and client, you can find you can only access this api using this azure token using the client credential flow.

Comment: But the api doesn't need authentication or authorization.

Comment: @FranklinWhale a bit confused, if don't need authentication where do you use oauth

Comment: The api calls another api that requires oauth

Comment: @FranklinWhale You can regard my answer api as api2.  Then in api1 you can  get token and access api2.